# Harry Turtledove's non-alternate-history sf

Tags: harry-turtledove

Which of [Harry Turtledove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Turtledove)'s sf¹ works are *not* alternate history?

The only one I know of is *The Case of the Toxic Spell Dump*. There's possibly the [Videssos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videssos) series, from the Wikipedia description. What else?

¹ 
<sub>By sf, I mean any speculative fiction, whether it's science fiction, fantasy, or other subcategory, but not “mundane” historical novels.</sub>

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me. Direct, answerable... if you're going to close it, Mr. Moderator, close it for not being a "true" sci-fi question. I vote to reopen.

Comment: A list would definitely be finite, so it's not really a "list" question that can go on and on and is never resolved.

Comment: @Mark: Ok, clearly you and I have different tastes in question titles. If you object to my rollback, let's please discuss it on Meta or in chat.

Comment: My bad. Yeah, I'll run it by you, I just wanted to make the title a question, sorry for stepping on your feet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [site](http://www.harry-turtledove.com/) that [lists all Harry Turtledove's book with an indication of what type of book it is.](http://www.dougr.orconhosting.net.nz/List.htm)

Comment: Except that list categorizes works as *either* SF *or* T[rue history], never both.

Answer (score 4):

Probably dozens. There's a very rich wiki devoted to him at http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Turtledove_Wiki

Comment: On this page, like others I found when googling, I can find a list of his alternate history writings. I'm looking for a list of *the rest*, in a more manageable form that taking the full list and crossing off the elements of the alt-hist list.

Comment: It might not exist. You might want to get in touch with some people at that wiki and start a Non-Alternative History category there. The community can pitch in and the list will be built over time.